# Submenu with z-index doesn't want to go over content

Tags: html, css, navigation

For some unknown reason z-index doesn't seem to work. I try to make the submenu. i.e. the 2nd bar. To go over the #content which it fails to do....

http://jsfiddle.net/PaD2v/

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Мэрия Skrillax-RP</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One&subset=cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="master.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="banner"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/f2EWgQP.png?1"><p id="banner text"></div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="#">Главная Страница</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Задачи</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="">Охрана</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Министерство Обороны</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Министерство Юстиций</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Министерство Культуры</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Министрество</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Список Сотрудников</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Hello2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Вакансии</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Авторизация</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="content">
                <p>Hello! Welcome to the www.mayor.freeiz.com!<br><br> Currently I am working on adding different types of information</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="footer">Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height:;
}
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.gtagaming.com/images/potd/200604/10501.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    width:1024px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#banner {
    height:216px;
}
#navigation {
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: orange;
    font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
    opacity:0.8;
    z-index: 15000001;

}

#navigation>li {
    float:left;
    
}
#navigation a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 10px;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    width:183.81px;
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation a:hover {
    background-color:white;
    color:blue;
    border-top:3px solid red;
    opacity:0.9999;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
#banner h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 1024px;
}
#content {
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    background-color:white;
    opacity:0.9;
    clear: both;
    z-index:1;
}

#content p{
    position:relative;
    top:6px;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index:1;
}

#footer {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: orange;
    width:1024px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.submenu {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    
}
.submenu li {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
#navigation li:hover .submenu {
    display:block;
    z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `relative` position in your `.submenu` use `absolute` position

css

```
.submenu {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;  
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PaD2v/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Relative positioning doesn't take the element out of the normal document flow. Consequently, when it appears it takes up space like a normal `div` and pushes everything beneath it down.

To remove it from the normal document flow so that it just sits on top of everything, use `position: absolute`. In this case, the thing we want to sit on top of everything is the submenu, so apply it to `.submenu`.